# I have bitcoins in Poloniex. How do I get them to CANADIAN dollars?

Tags: exchanges, client, canada

- Coin base doesn't allow transfer to a CANADA account and Kraken's authentication is down.
- it looks like I can get money out of Quadrigacx?? but how do I transfer my bitcoins from Poloniex to Quadrigacx
- am I totally off and there is another way? I'm ready to cash out and would like my bitcoin in cash!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it looks like I can get money out of Quadrigacx?? but how do I transfer my bitcoins from Poloniex to Quadrigacx

You will need to register and verify your account with Quadrigacx. Next obtain a deposit address for your Quadrigacx account, and initiate a withdrawl from Poloniex to the Quadrigacx address. After some time, your Quadrigacx account will be credited with the bitcoin.

> am I totally off and there is another way? I'm ready to cash out and would like my bitcoin in cash!

You could find someone to sell them to in person. There are some websites that facilitate this, such as [Local Bitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/).